# Rails Engine Helpers not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, helper, rails-engines

I am creating a Rails engine and I have some problem to load automaticly helpers methods from application_helper in my engine app directory. In fact for some controllers, they are loaded but for other one, they are not.

Any idea of the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Rails 3.1, but using Rails 3.0.11 I solved my problem by adding this to my Gemfile which then autoloads those helpers in the engines:

`gem "rails_helpers_fix"`

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1905-apphelpers-within-plugin-not-being-mixed-in#ticket-1905-22